# C http request gzip (zlib)

Tags: http, gzip, zlib

I'm making http requests using winsock and I need to parse the response. The problem is that some sites gzip no matter what I specify in my request header. I've even tried downgrading the request to `HTTP/1.0` with no success. So now I'm to add deflate/gzip support and having no luck. I had my program write the compressed content to file. Then I tried decompressing it with the `gzip` tool but it gave an error saying that it was a multi part gzip file. After some reading I found out that this is caused by the gzip header being corrupted due to not being handled as a binary. I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write the gzipped data to a file, have you opened it as a binary file? Assuming you are using C as in the title, did you open with **fopen(..., "wb")**?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help. It actually wrote the exact same thing to the file.

Comment: Are you reading from the web server using a FILE stream? In that case, is that one opened as binary?